# Имеется проблема со стабильностью печати используя принтер Qln 320 Zebra используя Zebra SDK

Tags: ios, print, sdk

Имеется принтер Zebra QLn320 с прошивкой версии V68.19.7Z используется совместно с приложением под  iOS
Я использую Zebra SDK и вот код кнопки печать:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^ {
    // Instantiate connection to Zebra Bluetooth accessory
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *serialNumber = [defaults valueForKey:@"selectedPrinterSN"];
    id<ZebraPrinterConnection, NSObject> thePrinterConn = [[MfiBtPrinterConnection alloc] initWithSerialNumber:serialNumber];

    BOOL success = [thePrinterConn open];

    NSString *zplData = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"^XA" \
                         @"^LH20,20^POI" \
                         @"^FT5,5^FH^A0N,30,30^FD%@^FS" \
                         @"^FT5,45^FH^A0N,30,30^FD%@^FS" \
                         @"^XZ" \
                         , @“Line1”, @“Line2”];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableData *data = [[zplData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

    long blockSize = 1024;
    long totalSize = data.length;
    long bytesRemaining = totalSize;
    while (bytesRemaining > 0) {
        long bytesToSend = MIN(blockSize, bytesRemaining);
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, bytesToSend);

        NSData *partialLabel = [data subdataWithRange:range];
        [thePrinterConn write:partialLabel error:&error];

        bytesRemaining -= bytesToSend;

        [data replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:NULL length:0];
        if (error) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [thePrinterConn close];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          //Update UI on the main queue!
    });
});
```

Имеется кнопка "Печать этикетки" на интерфейсе, который запускает печать этикетки.

Когда нажимаю кнопку "Печать" бывает такое что ничего не печатается (1-4 раза из 10 нажатий в общем), ошибка никакая не высвечивается из `MfiBtPrinterConnection`.

Пробовали менять тайм-аут но это не помогло.

На форуме разработчиков Zebra ответа никто не дает.

```
[((MfiBtPrinterConnection*)thePrinterConn) setTimeToWaitAfterWriteInMilliseconds:30];
```

Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой или может кто даст совет?

Есть один нюанс, при нажатии на печать, на принтере мигает индикатор что данные ему поступают, но даже когда печать не происходит, на принтере все равно горит индикатор что данные он получает.

Comment: а вопрос в чем?

Comment: А, нашел. там пол вопроса отформатировалось как код (внизу)

Comment: А теперь, Федя, скажи Васе все, что ты ему сказал раньше, на нормальном, на гражданском языке.

Comment: Действительно, чего бы Вам не написать письмо в Zebra и|или Apple. На ихних знаках изъясняться умеете. Там быстрее помогут.

Comment: 30 миллисекунд какой то маленький таймаут. Может хотя бы секунду попробуйте?

Comment: Max, 30 миллисекунд советуют как стандарт на форуме разработчиков, но на самом деле пробовали разные варианты.15млс,30млс,60млс,100млс но ничего не изменилось.